# How to update GIF to always loop infinitely using Transloadit

Tags: c#, gif, animated-gif, transloadit

From my understanding, the gif loop count is dependent on the gif file itself, so I'm trying to figure out a C# way to always update a gif's loop count to ensure it always loops infinitely.

I've been trying to do this with [Transloadit](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/), but I haven't been able to adjust the loop count at all. I've tried setting it to infinite as well as a specific amount, like loop twice, just to see if I could change it but it always keeps the gif's original loop count.

Some things I've tried are:

- Using [image/resize](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/image-manipulation/image-resize/) robot and adding `ImageMagick` params for setting a loop count
- Using [video/encode](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/video-encoding/video-encode/) robot with `ffmpeg` params for setting a loop count
- Using [image/resize](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/image-manipulation/image-resize/) robot to convert the gif into a gif (with and without `ImageMagick` params)

I know it's possible to adjust this directly with `ImageMagick` and `ffmpeg` but need to use Transloadit, as that's how we're managing S3 uploading. In case it helps, because we're using S3, I'm always referencing the `import` when trying these conversions.

Here's an example attempt of mine.

```
_steps.encode = new
{
  use = "import",
  result = true,
  robot = "/video/encode",
  ffmpeg_stack = "v3.3.3",
  ffmpeg = new
  {
    f = "gif",
    loop = 0
  }
};
```

Hoping there's some Transloadit flag or pattern that I'm not aware of...

Answer (score 0):

TIL `ffmpeg` updated its loop keys, so though the documentation says to use `-1` for infinite loop, my version worked with `0`. So my example above ended up being the answer, I definitely tried it before but one last try ended up doing the trick lol ️